# Find records combining two joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables:

User, House and HouseEvent

A House has a foreign_key (user_id) to User and an HouseEvent has a foreign_key (house_id) to House

You can see the schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f08db/5 -

I know how I can get all the users which do not have a house:

`SELECT * FROM User
LEFT OUTER JOIN House u ON u.user_id = user.id
WHERE u.user_id IS NULL`

But how could I get in a single query, all the users who do not have a house and those users who have a house with at (least) a suspended event.

So, in the example, I would get `Lee` because he does not have a house, and I would also get `John`, because even though he has houses, one of its houses has an associated suspended event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` the 2 queries together?

```
SELECT u.id, u.name  FROM User u
JOIN House h ON h.user_id = u.id
JOIN HouseEvent he ON he.house_id = h.id AND he.name = 'suspended'
UNION
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM user u
LEFT JOIN house h ON h.user_id = u.id
WHERE h.user_id IS NULL
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f08db/19)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM User
Where id not in (SELECT user_id FROM House) OR
id in (select user_id from House h, HouseEvent he where he.house_id = h.id AND he.id = 2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f08db/41

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without using `SUB QUERY`, just use `LEFT JOIN` here is the query:

```
    SELECT User.name FROM User
    LEFT JOIN House h on h.user_id = user.id
    LEFT JOIN HouseEvent e on h.user_id = e.house_id
    WHERE h.user_id IS NULL OR e.name = 'suspended'
    GROUP BY User.name
```

[I modified your SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f08db/49)

Comment: nice! Why do we need the group by?

Comment: @HommerSmith , We use `GROUP BY` in that `JOIN` to avoid displaying duplicate name, glad that it helps, if this resolve your problem, kindly mark as answer :)

Comment: Thanks Japz, how would I do it if I want to modify the query to get those users who dont have any houses as well as those users who have some houses which the last event is declined (there is a date column in houseEvent)

Comment: @HommerSmith, in that case what is your desired result ?