# Use last record to satisfy a requirement in a JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables:

User, House and HouseEvent

A House has a foreign_key (user_id) to User and an HouseEvent has a foreign_key (house_id) to House

I want to be able to get all the Users who **do not have a house** or **have a house which last associated event name is suspended** (not all the houses have events though)

The approach I have now is just taking the users who do not have a house, or the users who have any event that is suspended, by doing this:

```
SELECT User.name FROM User
LEFT JOIN House h on h.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN HouseEvent e on h.user_id = e.house_id
WHERE h.user_id IS NULL OR e.name = 'suspended'
GROUP BY User.name
```

How could I modify that query so that I get all the users who do not have any houses AND those users who have any houses which last event is suspended. In the query above, I'm taking just taking into account if there is any suspended event, not taking into consideration that is the last one associated with that house.

Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0f235

Comment: this was asked yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028458/find-records-combining-two-joins

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Do you just want to take out the first left join?

Comment: @vkp that is a different question - I am modifying my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like this. I had to refer to the schema in the fiddle for some of the info:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM
    User u
    LEFT JOIN House h on h.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        HouseEvent e INNER JOIN (
            SELECT house_id, max(date) AS max_date
            FROM HouseEvents
            GROUP BY house_id
        ) e2
            ON e2.house_id = e.house_id AND e2.max_date = e.date
    ) on h.user_id = e.house_id
WHERE h.user_id IS NULL OR e.name = 'suspended'
GROUP BY u.name
```

I'm not clear whether you want most recent "suspended" dates only or most recent of all events. I wrote it as an inner join because I think you might have problems if I just chained it as another left join at the end of all the others.

And I don't see how `id`, `user_id` and `house_id` can all refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect use case for [`WINDOW FUNCTIONS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html) which I think improves readability of a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_name
FROM (
    SELECT u.name as user_name, h.user_id as house_user_id,
           /*1*/ last_value(e.name) OVER (PARTITION BY u.id
                                    ORDER BY e.date ASC NULLS FIRST) as last_event_for_user
    FROM
        User u
        LEFT JOIN House h ON h.user_id = u.id
        LEFT JOIN HouseEvent e ON h.user_id = e.house_id /*2*/
) as sub
WHERE
    sub.house_user_id IS NULL
    OR sub.last_event_for_user='suspended'
```

The magic happens in line `/*1*/` where we get last value of `name` column in particular order (and for each `user_id`). Then in higher level query we just fetch rows without house and those with 'suspended' as last event.

Foot note: I believe that join expression of yours (`/*2*/`) is correct and `user_id` is `PRIMARY KEY` for `House` table.